# QRScanner library not found on marshmallow device

Tags: android

Hi i am getting this error when loading the library zbar
zbar.jar and zxing-2.1jar is under app/libs

libiconv.so and libzbarjni.so is under app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a

im using this to load the library inside my class

```
System.loadLibrary("iconv");
```

and added this to app level build.gradle

```
compile files('libs/zbar.jar')
compile files('libs/zxing-2.1.jar')
```

setup for my app level build.grade and i cannot change it to 22 or 23 which i have read for some to fix the issue

```
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.tagcash"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    multiDexEnabled true
```

anyone got a solution to this? everything works fine if version is lollipop and below. if version is marshmallow it crashes

whole stacktrace

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                         Process: com.tagcash, PID: 27216
                                                         java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.tagcash-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.tagcash-2/lib/x86, /data/app/com.tagcash-2/base.apk!/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libiconv.so"
                                                             at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:367)
                                                             at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
                                                             at com.tagbond.activity.QRScannerActivity.<clinit>(QRScannerActivity.java:66)
                                                             at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Thanks, hope someone could help.

Comment: Just want to know why are you using zbar and zxing both?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, maybe only one of those is being used. project is a little bit messy and haven't much seen what and where it's used.

Comment: I think this might be a dexing issue. Have you used `MultiDex.install(this);` in your app?

Comment: Try not to include both..I have got an experience how terrible it is to have both..the debugging becomes a headache as parts of some zbar and zxing are used.

Comment: yes i got MultiDex.install(this); on my application class.

Comment: @Akshay i will try not to include both. i've tried one zxing is not being used and only zbar is being used by the app